# Failure Rate calculation based on manufacturing defects (capacitor)

Tags: capacitor, modeling, reliability, manufacturing-process

Electronics failure rates typically follow the exponential distribution and models like Prism, Mil-Hdbk-217 or 217Plus (newer) are used to predict failure rates.

We are currently in the production phase and fielding our electro-mechanical systems but there seems to be a manufacturing defect within the capacitors by the vendor where much higher failures are being experienced attributed to knit-line defects or delamination at the electrode-dielectric junction, and the failures are occurring during final testing just prior fielding or even after they have been fielded.

My question is, if the capacitor have been modeled using our assumptions (exponential dist, power, vibe and thermal stresses), and manufacturing defects or screening escapes have occurred, then doesn't this mean that our modeled failure rate is NOT relevant anymore? Even calculating a point estimated failure rate (number of failures/accrued number of hours) is pointless (pun, ha) since this particular failure trend is un-modeled and a point estimate only represents a failure rate up until that point in time, and tomorrow we could realize we have many more failures in the field and that failure rate isn't a rate as expected.

How can this new failure rate be calculated/modeled given this manufacturing defect/screening escape? I realize the best thing to do is to chase the root cause and have corrective actions in place but at this point that is difficult as there are many fielded systems already in place.

Comment: “failures are occuring during final testing”. Can you guarantee the root cause is in the vendor and not in your design? What analysis have you done so far?

Comment: I forgot to add, the parts are NOT being overstressed in any way, they are operating at 60% rated voltage (derated).  Multiple parts from various lots have been CSAM'd (confocal scanning acoustic microscopy) and the delaminations and defects are found at a much higher % than promised.

Comment: Don’t be so sure. Over voltage is not the only failure mode in a capacitor. Thermal and mechanical stresses accounts for much more failures because they are harder to design. Have you checked that too? What’s the application? What kind of capacitor is this?

Comment: Yes, thermal is fine, operating at less than 50% of max rated temp, ambient is fine, also looked at power cycling but that is not a factor either.  Neither is mechanical or vibe induced stress an issue.  It is a 2125 sized MLCC, or ceramic capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

So if you’re positively sure the failure comes from the vendor your original assumption that the capacitor will eventually fail given an exponential distribution is false. This distribution applies to random events caused by the component’s exposure to time and stresses. What you seem to be experiencing is a quality issue normally expressed in ppm by the manufacturer. What is odd is that from your explanation this is being unexpectedly high. My suggestion is to get in touch with the manufacturer and request for an analysis of one of your defective capacitors. At the same time check the ppm of this component to realize the correct failure rate you should expect before going into field.

Comment: The manufacturer is aware if the issues, they are most likely screening escapes since that portion of the process relies on a visual inspection.   So more capacitors are escaping the screening process and these caps now have worse knit-line defects or delaminations which SHOULD have been caught during the screening process.

Comment: Ok, so it confirms that your supplier’s ppm is causing the problems

Comment: I already know the root cause is the manufacturer's process.  I just would like to know how to model this defect into the current model?

Comment: The model is simply a probability of x ppm being defective. Nothing more to do here

Comment: If you say is correct then use automotive rated parts they cost more but they typically do not this type of problem. The parts will cost more but the cost of manufacturing will go down when you are not doing all the additional labor and testing. Currently automotive is measuring defects in ppb.